# PyCharm goes straight to process finished with exit code 0 instead of breakpoints

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, ide, breakpoints

I am using PyCharm for leetcode problems, and I ran a code from neetcode for problem #15 3Sum. I put breakpoints in the IDE to go over each iteration, but when I click on debug it says: Process finished with exit code 0
I know exit code 0 means there are no errors in the code, but what I care is to go over each iteration to understand the approach used for the solution:

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p5In.png)
[after clicking on debug icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bot3m.png)

I tried print statements to see if it will display something.

Comment: dont post pictures of code.... you need to instantiate your class and call the method on the instance ...

Comment: Are you calling the function? You need `Solution().threesum([-3, 1, 0, -1, -3. 2])`

Comment: You should print the messages in the function, not when the class is being defined.